# How I can create multiple select-2 on a loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, select, dom-events

I am creating a form that allows me to add items from a database.I can add the amount of items that I need. I can also select the type of item I will select.

The problem happens that when I give the button to add another item this load but at the same time eliminates the functionality of select-2 of the other select.
This is my code;

I use jQuery and select-2 and bootstrap.

I  try load  after  the page load but  this doesn't  work;  I set  this  out  of a   `.onloaddocument`:

```
$('.select-dinamic').select2({ width: '100%' });
$("#button_new_equip").click(function(event) {
var select_buton='<div class="from-group  mt-1"><div class="row "><div class="col-3"><select class="select-dinamic col" name="" id="instrument0"><option value="qwqwqw">wewewewe</option></select></div><div class="col-8"><select class="select-dinamic col" name="" id="Tip"><option value="qwqwqw">wewewewe</option></select></div></div></div><br>'

  $("#Insp_instruments").append(select_buton)
  $('.select-dinamic').select2({ width: '100%' });
  /* Act on the event */
});

html
<div class="card container  ">
<div class="" id="Insp_instruments">
  <div class="from-group">
    <button type="button"id="button_new_equip" class="btn btn-primary "name="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
<br>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If  I  try  to  add  new  select2   in the form
the previous select lost the  select2 
properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a static `id` attribute for all the new dropdowns that you are creating on runtime, i.e `id="instrument0"` and `id="Tip"`.

So

- Either remove the `id` attribute from your html and it will work
- or otherwise make them unique by adding a counter using `$('.select-dinamic').length`

The second will be better to adapt and you have to change the ids for both the select to the following

- `id="instrument_' + $('.select-dinamic').length + '"`
- `id="Tip_' + $('.select-dinamic').length + '"`

See working demo below

```js
$("#button_new_equip").on('click', function(event) {
  var select_buton = '<div class="from-group  mt-1"><div class="row "><div class="col-3"><select class="select-dinamic col" name="" id="instrument_' + $('.select-dinamic').length + '"><option value="qwqwqw">wewewewe</option></select></div><div class="col-8"><select class="select-dinamic col" name="" id="Tip_' + $('.select-dinamic').length + '"><option value="qwqwqw">wewewewe</option></select></div></div></div><br>';

  $("#Insp_instruments").append(select_buton);
  $('.select-dinamic').select2({
    width: '100%'
  });

  /* Act on the event */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.9/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.9/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c08b275b91.js"></script>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card container">
  <div class="" id="Insp_instruments">


    <div class="from-group">
      <button type="button" id="button_new_equip" class="btn btn-primary " name="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>

    <br>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @FOXSHOOT see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: i appreciate @FOXSHOOT